# Export the six chart side by side in highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have to export the six chart side by side on button click after googling,I found example for multiple chart export and i have implemented the similar code but not able to export side by side.

> `My Implemented code:`[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sameekmishra/jLmdwvte/10/)

## Experted export chart:

[image]

Please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: I have changed you code a little bit. Look at this example: http://pastebin.com/9CbQkiNa

Comment: It work for me,Thanks.