# How to export multiple charts in HighCharts to one file (png, jpeg, pdf)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts

I have a requirement where in I am supposed to export multiple highcharts into one file (png, jpeg, pdf).
The image below shows my 2 piecharts. (there could be multiple charts).
[image]
I would like to have a button, which gives me output exactly like  above image in png, jpeg and pdf.

FYI, I have gone through below references but doesn't seem to work.

1. `http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiple`
2. `http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/gd7bB/`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you build an HTML page with all the charts you need there's tools that can convert HTML to images like e.g. [phantomJS with the rasterize script](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js).

Comment: Here you can find information how you can export multiple charts to one pdf/image: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiple You can also look at this SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38439310/export-the-six-chart-side-by-side-in-highchart#comment64286547_38439310

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. the link http://pastebin.com/9CbQkiNa exports blank image.

Comment: Doesn't help? can you be more specific? This is a question that has been asked and answered many times, and has working solutions (like the one that "doesn't help", above).  Do some searching for the other solutions that have been put out there. ( https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+export+multiple+charts+in+HighCharts+to+one+file ) In the meantime, how about a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses our external server to format Highcharts to PDF.

See http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.HighCharts and select "Download" ... "As PDF".

There is also image formats. Documentation to setup is here:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.APIDoc.Usage

Note: I am one of the contributors to this software.

Comment: how about the dependency ? what if some parameters change/updtes ?

Comment: It functions by scraping the svg as-is in the client. So as long as your dynamic step has executed it will render that result.

Comment: I have written this way on button click for downloading 'png':---- return xepOnline.Formatter.Format('container', { render: 'download', mimeType: 'image/png', filename: fName, pageWidth: '420mm', pageHeight: '297mm' });  --- but i am getting output as ".pdf" is this an issue ???

Comment: for 'render' ... download does not support images at this time, you have to use newwin or embed

Comment: oh okay. But that will be a problem where i need to allow "pop-up blocker" in case of "newWin". Any alternatives ?

Comment: We would have to implement the image code on the server for the download method. I will look into it in the next few days.

Comment: Alternatively you could modify the javascript yourself to do this because the base encoded image is returned. Instead of a new window just decode and save.